# One-to-Many Queries

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have 2 entities `Professionel` and `Article`.

The relation from `Professionel` to `Article` is **One-to-Many.**

This is `Article` class:

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "Article.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Article a")
    public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    private String description;
    private String photo;
    private String titre;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idprof")
    private Professionel professionel;
```

and this is `Professionel` class,

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(name = "Professionel.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Professionel p")
    public class Professionel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String address;
    private String altitude;
    private String cin;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String mail;
    private String motdepasse;
    private String nom;
    private String phone;
    private String prenom;
    private String ville;
    private String photo;
    private String profession;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professionel")
    private List<Article> articles;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professionel")
    private List<Experience> experiences;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professionel")
    private List<Formation> formations;
```

I want to display *all the articles belonging to a professionel* so that i write this function:

```
    public List<Article> listerArticleById(int id) {
    List<Article> articles = getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT article FROM Article article WHERE article.idprof=:param1")
            .setParameter("param1", id).getResultList();
    return articles;
}
```

But this function doesn't work

Comment: Change to `WHERE article.professionel.id=:param1`

Comment: I'd also recommend to take a look at [Criteria API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Comment: @Unda why is this relevant here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA maps to objects and their attributes, not tables and their columns.  As cy3er has said in his comment, changing :

```
public List<Article> listerArticleById(int id) {
    List<Article> articles = getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT article FROM Article article WHERE article.idprof=:param1")
            .setParameter("param1", id).getResultList();
    return articles;
}
```

to:

```
public List<Article> listerArticleById(int id) {
    List<Article> articles = getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT article FROM Article article WHERE article.professionel.id=:param1")
            .setParameter("param1", id).getResultList();
    return articles;
}
```

Should resolve your problem.  This is because the class `Article` contains the attribute `private Professionel professionel`, and the class `Professionel` contains the attribute `private int id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT article FROM Article article WHERE article.idprof=:param1
```

This is kind of JPA query called `JPQL`. The query statement are relevant to **entity and its properties (fields)**. So your query shouldn't include the underlying table and its column names.

Try with this query built on entity and property;

```
SELECT article FROM Article article WHERE article.professionel.id=:param1
```

See this [JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html)